# Is there a simple way to convert cset printout to a simple comma separated list?

Tags: string, bash, go

I am using the cset command to isolate sore cores in a sub set of all cores.
When I list the cores,they are printed in a smart way to save space.
Is it possible with some bash trix to convert the list to simple comma separated list?
A solution in go could also be useful for me.

```
cset set --list system
cset:
         Name       CPUs-X    MEMs-X Tasks Subs Path
 ------------ ---------- - ------- - ----- ---- ----------
       system 0-8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26-44,46,48,50,52,54,56,58-63 n       0 n   286    0 ...
```

I would like to see the list like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you facing? Hint: check the [`strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package, the `strings.Fields()` and `strings.Split()` functions might come handy.

Comment: I haven't tried much yet but thought this might be a general problem that there are answers to in bash. I will try the strings package.